# How to use Wald's equation to determine expectation in gambling model?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, gambling

$\begin{array}{l}{\text { In each game played one is equally likely to either win or lose 1. Let } S \text { be your }} \\ {\text { cumulative winnings if you use the strategy that quits playing if you win the first }} \\ {\text { game, and plays two more games and then quits if you lose the first game. }} \\ {\text { (a) Use Wald's equation to determine } E[S] \text { . }} \end{array}$

Let $X_i$ be the amount won in game $i$. 
$$E[S] =E\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\bigg]$$ 
Applying Walds theorem, 
$$=E[N]E[X]$$
And since this is a fair game where the player starts with 0 dollars, we know that $E[X]=0$. So, $E[S]=0$

**Is this correct?**

Comment: Suppose $E[S]\neq0$, then this strategy (or its reverse) has a positive expected value on a fair game which is impossible  So, in short, yes, it is true.

Comment: @StanTendijck Thank you for verifying. Could you also take a look and verify the following if you are able? [link to question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197689/determining-whether-counting-events-is-a-renewal-process)