# Determining whether counting events is a renewal process

Tags: probability, proof-verification

$\begin{array}{l}{\text { Consider a renewal process with mean interarrival time } \mu . \text { Suppose that each }} \\ {\text { event of this process is independently "counted" with probability } p . \text { Let } N_{C}(t)} \\ {\text { denote the number of counted events by time } t, t>0 \text { . }} \\ {\text { (a) Is } N_{C}(t), t \geqslant 0 \text { a renewal process? }} \\ {\text { (b) What is } \lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} N_{C}(t) / t ?}\end{array}$

#### **My Solutions**

**a)**
Yes this is a renewal process with mean interarrival time, $p\times\mu$

**b)**
Using the elementary renewal theorem we know that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{N(t)}{t} = \frac{1}{\mu}$$ 
So
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{N_C(t)}{t} = \frac{1}{p\times\mu}$$

> I was hoping someone could say whether this is correct?

Comment: According to your solution the mean interarrival time *decreases* when you only count each event with probability $p$. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: @kccu That is true. I think this is right now? $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} N_C(t)=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} pN(t)$$ and since $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{N(t)}{t}=\frac{1}{\mu}$$ it follows that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{ N_C(t)}{t}=p\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{N(t)}{t}=\frac{p}{\mu}$$

Comment: The statement $\lim_{t \to \infty} N_C(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} p N(t)$ does not really make sense, since both of these function are tending to infinity (I assume here $N(t)$ is the number of occurrences up to time $t$ when we count them all?). Do you want to say something like $\lim_{t \to \infty} N_C(t)/N(t)=p$? You would still need to justify this claim (and the claim that $N_C(t)$ is itself a renewal process).

Comment: @kccu I know the answer is $p/\mu$ but I cannot think of any other way of showing it other than what I did? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @kccu of course, multiply both sides by $p$. $$p\cdot\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{N(t)}{t}=p\cdot\frac{1}{\mu}$$

Comment: You are using:
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{N_C(t)}{t}=\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{N_C(t)}{N(t)} \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{N(t)}{t} = p \frac{1}{\mu}$$
but you have not justified *why* $\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{N_C(t)}{N(t)}=p$.

Comment: @kccu I am not sure how to justify that. Do you mind giving a hint

Comment: If $N(t)=n$, then $N_C(t)/N(t)= N_C(t)/n$ is the fraction or sample average of the first $n$ occurrences that are counted. Do you know anything about convergence of sample averages of independent random variables?

Comment: @kccu it converges to the proportion that is counted, $p$?

Comment: Yes, by the Strong Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: @kccu thank you. I was using this fact without proof as I thought it would be clear. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92785/discussion-between-jac-frall-and-kccu).